# jQuery validation followed by Ajax post

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to combine jQuery [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example) with Ajax post. This is my code:

PHP form:

```
<form id="newsletter_form" method="post">
    <input name="newsletteremail" type="text" id="newsletteremail" class="required email">
    <input name="Signup" type="submit" class="formsm" id="Signup" value="Signup">
    <div id="emailerrormessage"></div>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#newsletter_form').validate({
            rules: { 
                email: {required:true, email:true}
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/ajax.php?action=newsletter", 
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; iso-8859-7",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if(response.status == 'error'){

                            $("#newsletteremail").removeClass().addClass('ajaxerror');
                        } else {
                                                        $("#newsletteremail").removeClass();                            
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#emailerrormessage").addClass('ajaxsuccess').html(xhr.responseText).show();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Before using validate() the form would submit fine. After adding the validate() code, the validation works, the form is being submitted (I receive a 200 OK response) but the values being submitted are null. What am I doing wring here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the validator object that you're applying to the form, so change:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

to

```
data: $(form).serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.form plugin and try it as below,

```
submitHandler: function(form)
{
    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit(
    {
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend : function(arr, $form, options)
        {

        },
        success : function(msg)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```